# Python – How to mock a single function

Tags: python, mocking

From the Mock docs, I wasn't able to understand how to implement the following type of pattern successfully. `fetch_url` does not exist inside of a class.

My function in the `auth.py` file:

```
def fetch_url(url, method=urlfetch.GET, data=''):
    """Send a HTTP request"""

    result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, method=method, payload=data,
                            headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})

    return result.content
```

My test:

```
import unittest
from mock import Mock

class TestUrlFetch(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_fetch_url(self):
        from console.auth import fetch_url

        # Create a mock object based on the fetch_url function
        mock = Mock(spec=fetch_url)

        # Mock the fetch_url function
        content = mock.fetch_url('https://google.com')

        # Test that content is not empty
        self.assertIsNotNone(content)
```

If what I'm doing is completely in the wrong direction, please shed some light on the correct solution.

The test is not working, and is producing the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_fetch_url (console.tests.test_auth.TestUrlFetch)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bengrunfeld/Desktop/Work/code/wf-ghconsole/console/tests/test_auth.py", line 34, in test_fetch_url
    content = mock.fetch_url('https://google.com')
  File "/Users/bengrunfeld/.virtualenvs/env2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 658, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'fetch_url'
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
root: DEBUG: Using threading.local
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.277s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Does your test work? Why do *you think* you might be going in the wrong direction?

Comment: Good point! I included the test failure message. Things going wrong: I am not successfully creating a mock of `fetch_url`. The intended mocked behavior of `fetch_url` is not being created. `fetch_url` is not successfully being tested.

Comment: `Mock` creates a mock object intended to be used in lieu of the spec. So calling `mock.fetch_url` is incorrect if `mock` is a mock of `fetch_url`. You have to either call `mock('https://google.com')` directly, or have `mock` be a mock of `console.auth` instead.

Comment: @univerio, thanks for your answer. That worked. Shame you didn't put it into an answer, cause then I could have ticked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as univerio's comment suggests you should call you mock like this:

```
mock('https://google.com')
```

Your test should pass after that fix, but probably that mock doesn't do what you really want. I've encountered a few problems with `spec` and `autospec`.

1. Mocks created with `Mock(spec=)` don't check number of arguments they are called with. I've just looked through the docs and they don't state that, but for some reason I expected it to work. [Autospecced](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing) mocks do check the arguments.
2. By default both `spec` and `autospec` *function* mocks return mock objects when you call them. This may be not what you want when you mock a function that does not return anything. In this case you can set the `return_value` manually:

   ```
   def foo():
       pass

   mock_foo = Mock(spec=foo, return_value=None)
   mock_foo()
   ```